# Copy paste to different position using macro

Tags: excel, vba

i need the code to copy paste in the row below the last row with data in it. Ive wriiten the code to do this but instead of only picking data from E2:J9 its picking data from B2:J9 from the pivot.
How do i fix this.
Thanks

```
Sub aaaaaa()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Pivot_WH calculations") 'change name as needed

With ws
   'assumes data is in a "table" format with all data rows in column A and data columns in row 1
   Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
   lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   .Range(.Range("E2:J9"), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy _
    Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)


   .Range(.Range("A2:A9"), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy _
    Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: If you want data from only E2:J9, why are using lRow and lCol?

Comment: This `.Range(.Range("E2:J9"), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Copy` should  be `.Range("E2:J9").Copy`

Comment: Similarly for other Column

Comment: Thanks, i used a different code as the base for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Try**

```
Sub aaaaaa()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Pivot_WH calculations") 'change name as needed

With ws
   'assumes data is in a "table" format with all data rows in column A and data columns in row 1
   Dim lRow As Long, lCol As Long
   lRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   lCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   .Range("E2:J9").Copy _
    Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("L" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)


   .Range("A2:A9").Copy _
    Worksheets("WH Calc_new").Range("K" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(2)
End With

End Sub
```

When the Range is Specific, you don't need lrow & lcol as said by `AAA`

Comment: what can i do to add the date in a sequential order, i cant use a for loop as it will populate additional cells, how can i add code so that every next cell 7 days are added to the date. Thanks

Comment: You should ask a New question, clearly explaining the problem that you are facing.